# codeigniter - internationalization i18n - 404 Page Not Found

Tags: php, codeigniter, internationalization

I am using https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/CodeIgniter-2.1-internationalization-i18n, where I use it for multi-language support for website. I need to edit my routes to use the language parameters where I remove the method's name:

```
{domain}/{application}/{language}/{controller}/{method}/{parameter}
example: http://localhost/website/en/test/show/parameter
```

to

```
{domain}/{application}/{language}/{controller}/{parameter}
example: http://localhost/website/en/test/parameter
```

I set this in **routes.php**

```
$route['test/(:any)'] = "test/show/$1";

$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';    

$route['^(en|sk)/(.+)$'] = "$2";
$route['^(en|sk)$'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

### Problem:

When I use:

`http://localhost/website/en/test/show/parameter`

this is working great. But I applied

`$route['test/(:any)'] = "test/show/$1";`

and now when I use

`http://localhost/website/en/test/parameter`

it is not working. It show me 404 Page Not Found.

Thank you for your suggestions/code.

### Solution:

Figured out solution:

edit **routes.php**

```
$route['^(en|sk)/test/(:any)'] = "test/show/$2";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

Figured out solution:

edit **routes.php**

```
$route['^(en|sk)/test/(:any)'] = "test/show/$2";
```